# How to use the standard output by Flash Air?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I want to make a command line tool by Flash Air, but there is not any api of AS3 to output content to standard output.

Then, I try to use ANE to solve my problem(By making a windows ane and use C's  printf function to output content), but it doesn't work.

Is there any methods to use the standard output by Flash air, or to make a command line tool by Flash Air?

The code of dll written by c++ is:

```
FREObject add(FREContext ctx, void* functionData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
{
    int32_t x,y;
    FREGetObjectAsInt32(argv[0], &x);
    FREGetObjectAsInt32(argv[1], &y);


    int32_t result = x + y;
    FREObject resObj;
    FRENewObjectFromInt32(result, &resObj);

    //I want to use the "printf" to print content to the console
    printf("print by dll: the result is %d\n", result);

    return resObj;
}
```

Comment: http://redtamarin.com/about

Comment: no such thing in AIR.

Comment: I did not down-vote but, edit your question and show function code of how you try to **read** the `printf` output. Also keep to one topic. Command line tool? or reading some **.exe** output?

Comment: Thanks, @SushiHangover I will try the redtamarin.

Comment: @VC.One, I want to printf content to the standard output, like command line tool, not reading some.exe output. I will paste my dll's code of ane.

Comment: @chenze `I want to printf content to the standard output, like command line tool, NOT reading some.exe output` excuse me but how are the those two things different?? When you run a **C** program that has `printf` the **std output** usually shows up in terminal window right? How is AS3 involved? If you want to catch that terminal output and display inside your Flash app's user interface instead (it looks like a fake terminal?) then check the **[previous edit of my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35416724/1)** and have a textfield to show the terminal output.

Comment: If instead you want to send some text from AS3 to command line window then define a `var CMD_exe : File = new File("C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe");` later start a new process with some arguments `args.push("/k");` followed by `args.push("start echo THIS IS TEXT FROM AS3");` this will open a terminal window with text saying **THIS IS TEXT FROM AS3**. Why would you need it like this? Make your own textfield(s) in your Flash app and that shows what the user would have seen in that terminal window anyways (read terminal via progress Events). Actually showing the terminal is an unusual request.

Comment: Thanks a million, VC.One！I solved my problem. The std output by AIR ANE does work with python, I now use python to get my AIR's standard output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but there is not any api of AS3 to output content to standard output.

Only a running OS process can give **back** Standard Output (also called `stdio` in C).

The best you can do is create an app that looks like commandline tool but in reality it just runs & passes data to the actual (native) OS commandline tool. Meaning in your tool you capture the user command to a string and then run a `nativeProcess` involving that (parsed) string as your process arguments.

Example in your app user types : `calc`. Your AIR runs:  `c:\Windows\System32\calc.exe`

**Anyways, on to your real question...**

> I try to use C's printf function to output content, but it doesn't
>   work.

If you mean you made some **test.exe** with C and when you get AIR to run it you want to capture the `printf` output then you can try:

```
process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, CTest_OutputData);
```

or

```
process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, CTest_ErrorData);
```

To catch the output (it will be sent as bytes) make sure you have some **public** `byteArray` and `String` created. Here's an example for `STANDARD_ERROR_DATA` (it's likely the output goes here too, since you claim that `STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA` is not working).

The code shown below inside that function works same whichever type of `progressEvent` you choose. Just put in the "right" one. `temp_BA` is the byteArray variable you setup earlier.

```
public function CTest_ErrorData (event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    process.standardOutput.readBytes( temp_BA, temp_BA.length, process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable );

    if ( temp_BA.length > 0 )
    {
        temp_String = temp_BA.readUTFBytes(temp_BA.length);
        trace( "temp_String is : " + temp_String ); //if you want to check it
    }

}
```

**Final TIP:**  You can get traces inside Flash IDE by disabling "desktop" and keeping "extended desktop" ticked. Both must be ticked later when you make installing app.

Comment: Thanks a lot, VC.One. Sorry, I didn't clarify my problem. I want to output by my own air exe.

Comment: @chenze, check the new edit and let me know if it works.

Comment: I can get the result from the C program. I have tried your code that output by C++, I got the result from the program, but not output to the console even.